# Git Issue : Newly added folders are showing untracked

Tags: git, macos

I have cloned a empty git repository. and I have put my whole xcode application. Now I want to push these project to server, then It's showing the folder untracked.

Please look the attached screenshot. This folder contains multiple files and sub-folders.

[image]

Comment: Git never tracks (or commits) *folders*, only *files*. A folder (directory) may contain untracked files. `git status` will summarize them unless you use `git status -uall` or `git status --untracked-files=all`; the summary makes it look as though it's a single untracked folder, but it's not. (This has nothing to do with ios, nor objective-c, nor swift. it's just a Git issue. The mobile tag is probably also inappropriate.)

Comment: Did you `git add` the folder?

Comment: @Amadan: yes, and as I commented, using `git status -uall` will show the actual files, rather than summarizing them like this. Maybe it would help if I put it this way: the question above should be modified to include the output of `git status -uall` rather than that of `git status`. Also, please don't post photos of screenshots. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: git add . or git add -A would help you add all the untracked files.

Comment: @torek, amadan, swat, I copied the app folder inside the empty cloned repo. Now I run git status, It is showing my newly added folder as untracked. So I am unable to run add/commit/push

Comment: @Amadan, When I run git status -uall, I can see all the files inside ECGame folder. But these all files are showing under untracked. So I am unable to run the command add/commit/push.

Comment: `git add` on a file that is currently *untracked* copies that file into the index, so that now, that file is *tracked*. The index is where you build your next commit, and it contains a copy of *every* (tracked) file. Using `git add` on a folder (directory) name tells Git to add the files named `folder/file1`, `folder/file2`, and so on: Git doesn't really believe in folders at all, files just have names with slashes in them.

Comment: Why are you unable to git add the folder? Did you try running the command `git add ECGame` ?

Comment: As @torek explains, you can't push if you haven't committed; you can't commit if you haven't added; but there are no prerequisites for adding.

Comment: @Amadan: the issue was, apparently (see the OP's own answer), that the repository in use here was storing files with names containing Unicode characters that did not play well with the special MacOS `precomposeunicode` setting. We needed to see the actual file names, in order to be able to guess at the problem, and we were never shown those file names.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned, you would need to git add/git commit *before* pushing.

But if `ECGame` *content* is what you want, you would need to copy said content in your empty  cloned repository, not the folder itself.
As shown in your picture, if you add/commit/push, your remote repository would include the folder `ECGame/`, instead of directly their files.

If some files remains untracked even *after* a `git add`, then yes, [`core.precomposeUnicode`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coreprecomposeUnicode) might help:

> When false, file names are handled fully transparent by Git, which is backward compatible with older versions of Git.

But it should not be needed with recent versions of Git.
As explained in "[Git Tower / Untracked files with unicode names](https://www.git-tower.com/help/mac/faq-and-tips/faq/unicode-filenames)":

> The default for this config setting on OS X is true and there should be no reason to override it.
>   Note that the setting is also important when sharing repos between Macs.
>
> Once a file name has been added in decomposed form to a Git repository, the only way of solving the problem is to remove these files from Git and re-add them with `core.precomposeunicode` set to `true` on Mac OS X or perform this action on Linux or Windows.
>
> To recap, if you have problems with unicode file names showing up as untracked:
>
> - Make sure `core.precomposeunicode` is globally set to `true` on OS X
>
>   ```
>    $ git config --global core.precomposeunicode
>    => true
>   ```
> - All files still shown as untracked need to be removed from and re-added to Git.

Comment: I copied the app folder inside the empty cloned repo. Now I run git status, It is showing my newly added folder as untracked. So I am unable to run add/commit/push.

Comment: @VipinYadav Setting  `core.precomposeunicode` to `false` should not be the answer. See my edited answer and the associated article I reference.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what was the exact issue behind it But it has been resolved by below command

git config core.precomposeunicode false

Ref - http://oskarhane.com/untracked-files-in-newly-cloned-git-repo/

Comment: Had you shown the output of `git status -uall`, we could have seen the Unicode characters that lead to these issues on MacOS. That doesn't guarantee someone would have figured this out particularly quickly, of course.

Comment: Yes, I was able to see all the files and folder as untracked after running this command "git status -uall"